# Why can't I access par inside the function even if I use the keyword global in the following python program?

Tags: python-2.7, global-variables

I am trying to access the variable par (declared inside the main module) inside the function func(). But I am getting the exception 'global name par is not defined'. What am I doing wrong?

```
Main.py

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import Second as S
    par = {1 : 'one'}
    S.func2()

def func():
    global par
    print('In func')
    print(par[1])



Second.py

import Main as M

def func2():
    M.func()
```

Comment: How are you calling this? Note that the definition (why not just `par = {1: 'one'}`?) only happens when the script is run directly, not when it's imported.

Comment: I have modified my program to highlight what I want to achieve. I am now simply importing the module temp and I get the exception stated above.

Comment: Why do the two `import` each other? Which one are you actually running?

Comment: I am running the Main module directly. The two files importing each other might seem strange but I am doing this for debugging. Its not the it has to function normally.

Answer (score 1):

If you import the file, then the value of `__name__` wont be `"__main__"` and the `par` dict never gets defined. (`__name__` will instead be the name of the module, in this case `"temp"`)

`if __name__ == "__main__":` is used shield bits of code designed only to run when the script is run directly (ie `python temp.py`). If the file is imported, then that if condition will evaluate `False`.

I think the root of your confusion, is that normally if multiple python files import the same file they enter `sys.modules` as the same entry/object so they have the same namespace. However the main script that's invoked gets a special name (`__main__`) so if you happen to import it, python doesn't see it and creates a new python module object.

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import Second as S
    par = {1 : 'one'}
    S.func2()

def func():
    print(sys.modules["__main__"])  # here par is defined
    print(sys.modules["Second"].M)  # here it isn't
    global par
    print('In func')
    print(par[1])
```

Comment: I agree with you. I have modified my program to explain clearly what I am doing. Please tell me now what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @Shaun The `func` that's getting called is in the namespace `S.M.func`, in this namespace `__name__ != "__main__"`

Comment: @ GP89 : Please clarify further. I understand that func() is being called in the namespace S.M.func() but the par variable is also defined in the namespace M so shouldn't it be accessible to func(). If this is not possible, it would be great if you could suggest a way around this problem. Thanks

Comment: @Shaun `S.M.__name__ == 'Main'` so the if condition is `False` so when `S.M.func` is called, it throws the error. `par` has been defined in the main module, but `S.M` is a different object with its own namespace. What you're doing seems very odd, could you not just define `par` outside of the `__name__ == "__main__"` block?

Answer (score 0):

Your first example ran just fine on repl.it, but you probably did not run it as the main file. Your new example shows that you source the file in your second script, so `__name__=="__main__"` evaluates to false, ergo: 
par does not get initialized! 
Why do you include the if branch in the first place?

By the way, you do not need the global declaration if you just want to print par. Global is only required if you intend to change the value.